# How can I extract this part of code to the some reusable method?

Tags: python

I have several the same looking methods which I want to refactor to one generic use method. How to do that? Only one thing is different there 'assert_all_items_and_rows_for'.

```
def assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(config, index, item, row, asserts):
        if index == 0:
            def_platforms = config["pl"]
            platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32"]
            compare_name_from_definition_to_excel_name_for_platforms(config, def_platforms, platforms, row)
        assert_all_items_and_rows_for_boos(item, row)


def assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(config, index, item, row, asserts):
    if index == 0:
        def_platforms = config["pl"]
        platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32"]
        compare_name_from_definition_to_excel_name_for_platforms(config, def_platforms, platforms, row)
    assert_all_items_and_rows_for_ann(item, row)

def assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(config, index, item, row, asserts):
    if index == 0:
        def_platforms = config["pl"]
        platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32"]
        compare_name_from_definition_to_excel_name_for_platforms(config, def_platforms, platforms, row)
    assert_all_items_and_rows_for_gem(item, row)
```

or maybe could use something like this:

```
def assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(config, index, item, row, asserts):
    if asserts is "boos":
        if index == 0:
            def_platforms = config["platforms"]
            platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32"]
            compare_name_from_definition_to_excel_name_for_platforms(config, def_platforms, platforms, row)
        assert_all_items_and_rows_for_boos(item, row)
    elif asserts is "gem":
        if index == 0:
            def_platforms = config["platforms"]
            platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32"]
            compare_name_from_definition_to_excel_name_for_platforms(config, def_platforms, platforms, row)
        assert_all_items_and_rows_for_gem(item, row)
    else:
        raise Exception('wrong parameter')
```

Comment: Pass  the function (assert_all_items_and_rows_for_boos etc.) as an additional parameter to your method.

Comment: The example is a bit confusing because all of your functions have the same name. Also, there is quite a bit of data in there. Is the only difference `assert_all_items_and_rows_for_<whatever>`?

Comment: @ tdelaney yes the only difference is assert_all_items.... method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the different assert functions as an argument. For example:

```
def assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(config, index, item, row, asserts, assert_function):
    if index == 0:
        def_platforms = config["pl"]
        platforms = ["gp", "ios", "win32"]
        compare_name_from_definition_to_excel_name_for_platforms(config, def_platforms, platforms, row)
    assert_function(item, row)
```

And call them like this (I have put None for the first 5 arguments, keep what you have there.):

```
assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(None, None, None, None, None, assert_all_items_and_rows_for_boos)
assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(None, None, None, None, None, assert_all_items_and_rows_for_ann)
assert_all_items_and_rows_when_index_is_0(None, None, None, None, None, assert_all_items_and_rows_for_gem)
```